# Is General American Accent the only choice If I want learn an accent through the Internet that is understood by everyone?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, british-english, american-accent, accent

I am learning English. Please stop telling me accent is not important. If I want to understood by everyone I need to learn an accent. I know no matter how hard I try, I will never sound perfect. But learning 80% is enough for me.

Everytime anyone say they want to learn Received Pronunciation, [people will tell them not to learn it, as it sounds posh](https://www.reddit.com/r/languagelearning/comments/7c85r9/i_would_love_to_speak_with_proper_received/dpnx4a7/?context=3). So I think I should learn modern version of RP, but there is not enough resources on Youtube to learn it.

So is General American Accent the only choice for a non-native speaker who learn English through the internet?

Is it OK to learn General American Accent? Does a non-native speaker speak with a General American Accent sound ridiculous?

Comment: Learn any accent that's easy for *you*. ..... “*Does a non-native speaker speak with a General American Accent sound ridiculous?*”.. No, not at all.

Comment: I would say learn the accent of the APP that suits you best. My wife is studying English and she uses an American APP because it is the one available in her mother tongue. To be honest I find the English spoken on it very difficult to understand. The pronunciation is not clear words run in to each other and are spoken much too quickly. Without considering the awful accent and the bad grammar. Oh yes, and the misuse of our beautiful language.

Comment: It is OK to learn the General American accent and doesn't sound ridiculous.  It is also OK to learn Received Pronunciation, and I don't agree with those who've apparently said otherwise.  If you are planning or hoping to live or study in the UK (or Australia or NZ) then learning RP might be preferable (and if you are planning to live in N. America then learning General American might be preferable), but if you have no such plans then objectively there isn't much to choose between them.

Comment: Whether RP sounds posh is a matter of opinion and perspective, but generally speaking, to the extent that people judge each other by accent socially, it is more likely to create a positive impression than a negative one.  Also, while Brits may lightheartedly mock their mates for sounding posh, they may also mock them for sounding too "common", or for sounding too American.  But this isn't to be taken too seriously.

Comment: @Brad No offense but it sounds like your wife needs a  better app (not APP as it's not an acronym/initialism).

Comment: No offense taken. From my point of view you are exactly right but from her point of view she likes the Chinese instructions given by Duolingo. If she uses a Chinese "app" she only learns Chinglish.

Comment: [anyone says, with an s//So is **a** general American accent]

Comment: A similar question denouncing GA was posted on ELU the day before yesterday, twice at least. And another question like this was posted here on ELL yesterday and then the OP vandalized their own post. I don't quite get the obsession with GA.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question

Comment: RP or GA, it doesn't really matter. Pick whichever you are most comfortable with or that matches your travel / living requirements best. Listen to the radio and TV announcers and news readers, they are usually chosen for their clear pronunciation and universally understood accents. Please do not pick one of the heavy regional accents as you won't necessarily be understood. And if you get a chance, take lessons from a native English speaker (but again without a heavy regional accent). Unfortunately there are some who have not had the benefit of proper English teachers and are unintelligible.

Answer (score 6):

There are several points one could make here.

Whichever accent you choose you need to make sure you learn the appropriate dialect of English to go with it. It would sound odd if you speak with a perfect British accent and use words with their North American meaning and vice versa.

If you learn one way of speaking and then go to a country where they speak differently you should not find it too hard to adapt. At least that has been my experience with another international language (Spanish).

I am not sure who tells you RP sounds posh. We do have posh accents in the UK but they are not the same although they are closer to RP than they are to regional dialects.

So, in summary, do not worry too much. After all we will all understand you which is the main reason you are learning the language.